# what the '@' mean in linux veth name?

Tags: linux

when started the docker,i found the veth name contains '@'. as i konw, the veth pair name is `veth0@veth1` and `veth1@veth0` in gerenal. But i found the docker veth is `vethb00e848@if7`.

**So what the '@' means? or could i change the `veth0@xxx` to `veth0@yyy`?**

```
➜  ~ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:f7:28:67:b3:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:c5:d4:df:e9:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:78:12:f6:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-02c830829a97: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:32:81:fd:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-3000ca4de5c1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:52:5c:c6:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vethb00e848@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:34:e8:9f:b9:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

Comment: [this page](https://platform9.com/blog/container-namespaces-deep-dive-container-networking/) might have some answers, it suggests that the `@if#` part has the number of the entry of the other end of the `veth` pair, in your case `vethb00e848@if7` is one end, and the interface with index 7 is the other side (not shown in your output).  I don't know if anything requires that so I don't know if you could get away with changing it if you wanted to

Comment: The `@xxx` part changes to `@if#` with the kernel-internal number of the interface if the part on the other end is in a different network namespace, and therefore its name is not visible (which is one of the main usage cases for veth-pairs).